# Replace the text in an input text box with text from a selected autocomplete option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an input type text box with and auto complete options below it. Using the up and down arrows on the keyboard, you can move through the auto complete options and "select" one, making it turn red. How do I replace the text in the input box with the text of the selected option like is common place with search engines?

```
<input class="searchBox" id="searchBox" name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="hi">

<div class="autoSuggestContainer">
  <span>Select from Menu</span>
    <a>history</a>
    <a>hilton</a>
    <a>hip2save</a>
    <a>hillary clinton</a>
    <a>hickok45</a>
    <a>hitler</a>
    <a>hibiscus</a>
    <a>hipaa</a>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the code with the HTML, CSS, and Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/qckyu5e6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your fiddle you'll achieve that doing just this

```
$('.searchBox').val($(".selected").text());
```

If you want to trigger it you need to add a new case to handle 'enter' key on your keyDown event and also a click event

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:
      moveUp();
      break;      
    case 40:   
      moveDown();
      break;
    case 13:
      //handle enter key
      setInputText($(".selected").text());
      break;
    }
};

$(".urlnamelinkAS").on("click", function () {
    setInputText($(this).text());
});

function setInputText(text){
    $('.searchBox').val(text);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for my case, the urlnamelinkAS on click function is necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you set the selected class on move up and down you can retrieve the anchor tag with selected class text and assign it to the input tag. https://jsfiddle.net/b19uv25q/6/

```
    $("#searchBox").val($(".selected").text());
```